# facebook login form on third party website

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login

Facebook is blocked by my company firewall but I want to develop an app where in employees can click a link we send it to their email and provide access to their facebook account and update. Firewall blocks facebook.com so I cannot have users type their username and password on facebook.com url. Can I have users type in their username and passowrd on internal website using which the app will login and get access?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that against Facebook's policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it goes against the purpose of oauth to take the user's password and use it to log in as that user. oauth is designed so that the user will never have to disclose their password to your app but still be able to provide your app with some of their own facebook data. this way, only the facebook data which the user chooses to share will be available to your app. also the user may choose to allow your app to publish on their behalf, [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/publishing/) for the details.

my suggestion would be to get the users to authenticate your app from outside the work network (where the facbook.com url is available). this way you can still post on their behalf and your app can get certain information from their profile to relay on to them without you ever needing to know their password.